# How to prevent two dates from overlapping?

Tags: ember.js

In the `IndexController`, I have two properties, `from` and `to`, both containing an instance of the `Date` object.

I have set up one separate observer for each property and run my overlap-prevention logic in there -- is this the right approach?

Here's the JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/yijezebetaya/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that approach is perfectly acceptable.